# How to assign values to properties in moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a class with a method that returns an object of type `User`

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public virtual User GetUser(string username, string password, string email, bool isApproved)
    {
        return new User()
            {
                Name = username
                ,Password = EncodePassword(password)
                ,Email = email
                ,Status = (isApproved ? UsuarioStatusEnum.Ativo : UsuarioStatusEnum.ConfirmacaoPendente)
                // ...
            };
    }

    // ..
}
```

`User` is a domain object. Note the `Id` property with **setter as protected**:

```
public class User : IAuditable, IUser
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual UsuarioStatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

*Id is protected because it is generated by the database.*

### Test project

In my Test project I have a Fake repository with a method `Store` to save/update the object:

```
public void Store(T obj)
{
    if (obj.Id > 0)
        _context[obj.Id] = obj;
    else
    {
        var generateId =  _context.Values.Any() ? _context.Values.Max(p => p.Id) + 1 : 1;
        var stubUser = Mock.Get<T>(obj); // In test, will always mock
        stubUser.Setup(s => s.Id).Returns(generateId);
        _context.Add(generateId, stubUser.Object);
    }
}
```

In `CustomMembershipProvider` I have `public override MembershipUser CreateUser` method that calls the `GetUser` to create a `User`.
This way, all I have to do is mock the `GetUser` method so that the repository can generate the `Id`

```
var membershipMoq = new Mock<CustomMembershipProvider>();
membershipMoq.CallBase = true;
membershipMoq
    .Setup(p => p.GetUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
    .Returns<string, string, string, bool>( (username, password, email, isAproved) => {
        var moqUser = new Mock<User>();
        moqUser.Object.Name = username;
        moqUser.Object.Password = password;
        moqUser.Object.Email = email;
        moqUser.Object.Status = (isAproved ? UsuarioStatusEnum.Ativo : UsuarioStatusEnum.ConfirmacaoPendente);
        return moqUser.Object;
    });
_membershipProvider = membershipMoq.Object;
```

### Problem

In theory everything is correct. When `CreateUser` call 'GetUser' to create a user, the user will return Mock filled;

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateUser_deve_criar_usuario_no_repositorio()
{
    // Act
    MembershipCreateStatus status;
    var  usr = _membershipProvider.CreateUser(
        _fixture.Create<string>(),
        _fixture.Create<string>(),
        _fixture.Create<string>(),
        null, null, true, null,
        out status);

    // usr should have name, email password filled. But not!

    // Assert
    status.Should().Be(MembershipCreateStatus.Success);
}
```

The problem is that Email, Name, Password are empty (with default values)!

[image]

Comment: Which class you are testing here? I see only mocks around

Comment: I'm testing my `CustomMembershipProvider`.  `status.Should().Be(MembershipCreateStatus.Success);`    In the repository, the user created with e-mail, name and password empty.

Comment: `CustomMembershipProvider` is a mock in your code. You are testing moq framework?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy `CustomMembershipProvider` is a mock because he mocks one method on this class, but nevertheless calls the base implementation for every other method (because of `.CallBase = true`)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The way you prepare the mocked user is the problem.

```
moqUser.Object.Name = username;
```

will not set the name, unless you have setup the mock properly.
Try this before assigning values to properties:

```
moqUser.SetupAllProperties();
```

This method will prepare all properties on the mock to be able to record the assigned value, and replay it later (i.e. to act as real property).

You can also use **SetupProperty()** method to set up individual properties to be able to record the passed in value.

Another approach is:

```
var mockUser = Mock.Of<User>( m =>
    m.Name == "whatever" &&
    m.Email == "someone@example.com"); 

return mockUser;
```

Comment: You can use `SetupProperty` to do it one at a time, also

Comment: Thanks, I'll extend the answer

Comment: I don't think you can `.Verify` when you set the property value this way

Answer (score 11):

I think you are missing purpose of mocking. Mocks used to mock dependencies of class you are testing:

[image]

System under test (SUT) should be tested in isolation (i.e. separate from other units). Otherwise errors in dependencies will cause your SUTs tests to fail. Also you should not write tests for mocks. That gives you nothing, because mocks are not production code. Mocks are not executed in your application.

So, you should mock `CustomMembershipProvider` only if you are testing some unit, which depends on it (BTW it's better to create some abstraction like interface `ICustomMembershipProvider` to depend on).

Or, if you are writing tests for `CustomMembershipProvider` class, then it should not be mocked - only dependencies of this provider should be mocked.

Comment: In theory, you are right. Unless the method under test calls another virtual method on the same class, where CallBase = true comes into play. I agree this is bad design to start with, but sometimes people work with legacy code, etc.

Comment: @SunnyMilenov sorry, but in practice I never test mocks. Is there any examples when testing mock can be useful?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky excellent explanation. And I agree with you. In this particular case I test `CustomMembershipProvider`, specifically the creation of users: `CreateUser` method ..

Comment: .. Inside the `CreateUser` method, an object `User` is created call  `GetUser` method.  
But the `Id` property of my `User` object a setter is as protected (*Id is generated by the database*)...

Comment: **How can I test my class** `CustomMembershipProvider`? I need mock my domain object `User` So Id is always `.Max(p => p.Id) + 1`

Comment: @lzayberezovsky: in this concrete example he is not testing the mock, but CustomMembershipProviderClass. He just uses moq as a helper to let him override one particular method of it, instead of creating an inherited class, and override there. In this case, this is not a mock, but stub.

Comment: @ridermansb If you only need to get your own Id during user creation, then you should probably mock the database as this is the place where the Id is created.

Answer (score 2):

Specifies that the all properties on the mock should have "property behavior",
meaning that setting their value will cause them to be saved and later returned when the properties is requested.
(This is also known as "stubbing".)
The default value for each property will be the one generated as specified by the
property for the mock.

```
mock.SetupAllProperties();
```