# Modifying mock property which has been set up

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm going to simplify a bit the problem:

In my tests, I use a mocked object (I mocked it because it calls a bdd) which I give in parameters to a method of another object (not mocked) whose purpose is to modify a property of this mocked object.

```
ModifyingClass myModifyingClass = new ModifyingClass();
Mock<ToModifyClass> mockedClass = new Mock<ToModifyClass>();
mockedClass.Setup(mc => mc.name).Returns("Test1");
myModifyingClass.modify(mockedClass.Object);
```

The method `modify` then try to set the property name of the mocked object, but it won't work, so maybe it's the normal behavior but I really need to test if all of this work and if the method `modify` set the property as I want.

Comment: What happens when you run the test? Where the error occurs?

Comment: What mocking library is this? Regardless, you should stub not mock that property if you want to use it like a real property - how exactly you do that depends on the library.

Comment: Janis. S. I debug the test and no error happens, the property is just not modified.

Comment: How do you know it is not modified, do you have an assert statement?

Comment: Alex Paven, it's just the usual library Moq, include with visual studio, I didn't studied stud yet, I'll look at that maybe it can be better for my problem

Comment: No Janis S. I debug line by line and check if the property as been changed. When i send a real ToModifyClass (not mocked), the property is set and when it's a mock with a setup it's not

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816551/how-to-assign-values-to-properties-in-moq, you would need to call SetupAllProperties()

Comment: Janis S. I tried it It work if i don't setup the returns as i did in my example but I need to do it, I think I'm going to find another method because it's obviously not working like that :/ Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you need to setup the mocked class differently in order to retain the values passed to properties.

Reference [Moq - Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

> Stub all properties on a mock (not available on Silverlight):
>
> ```
> mock.SetupAllProperties();
> ```

The example test provided would then look like...

```
//Arrange
var myModifyingClass = new ModifyingClass();
var mockedClass = new Mock<ToModifyClass>();
mockedClass.SetupAllProperties(); //<-- this will allow property changes to be retained.
var model = mockedClass.Object;
//set the property now that it can be set
model.name = "Test1";
var expected = "expected value here";

//Act
myModifyingClass.modify(model);

//Assert
var actual = model.name;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
//... other assertions
```

Answer (score 0):

In Moq one would need to setup the getter.

```
mockedClass.SetupGet(mc => mc.name).Returns("Test1");
```

Comment: It won't work either, I think I get the "Test1" even if I set the property because of the setup/setupget. I'm finally not going to use setup and set the property myself, like that it works, thank you very much for your help