# Roslyn Analyzer for String comparison

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis

I want to write a roslyn analyzer for string comparison.
The cases are:
s1 can be a string.
So if s1.equals(s2) or s1 == s2; it should fix to string.equals(s1,s2,Stringcomparsion.Ordinal)

I got the basic understanding of tree and also i need to create a Analyzer file and a CodeFixProvider class.

So I tried to get the syntax tree for eg. s1.equals(s2).

Now for writing the Analyze code method, I do not know how to verify the s1 is either a string. So i need help here.

I am trying to follow this article, https://www.meziantou.net/writing-a-roslyn-analyzer.htm.

For eg.

```
Class{
  string s1 = "one";
  string s2 = "two";
  bool res = one.equals(two);
}
```

should refactor to:

```
Class{
  string s1 = "one";
  string s2 = "two";
  bool res = string.equals(one,two, StringComparsion.Ordinal);
}
```

Comment: Side note: while good educational experience, I don't think what you are trying to achieve is improvement of the code... and can easily break code if used in expression trees...

Comment: Side note 2: "string" is not an opposite of "const" - you may want to edit to clarify what you mean: pairs would be "const"/"variable" and "string / "any other type but string".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I updated it, can you explain how it could break the code? I am just changing the comparison type not the entire code.

Comment: I.e. you rewrite something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/16818415/477420 with `Equals` and it most likely will not work...

Comment: so what will work? i need to get the data type of s1

Comment: You can find an implementation at https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator

Answer (score 0):

You can check the implementation of the rule MA0006: [GitHub](https://github.com/meziantou/Meziantou.Analyzer/blob/c1e41c25125b78d3429543d3c0abc5b5187bc0e5/src/Meziantou.Analyzer/Rules/UseStringEqualsAnalyzer.cs)

You can also check my post about string comparisons for other analyzers for strings: https://www.meziantou.net/string-comparisons-are-harder-than-it-seems.htm#getting-warnings-in

```cs
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public sealed class UseStringEqualsAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
            context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);

            context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeInvocation, OperationKind.BinaryOperator);
        }

        private static void AnalyzeInvocation(OperationAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var operation = (IBinaryOperation)context.Operation;
            if (operation.OperatorKind == BinaryOperatorKind.Equals ||
                operation.OperatorKind == BinaryOperatorKind.NotEquals)
            {
                if (operation.LeftOperand.Type.IsString() && operation.RightOperand.Type.IsString())
                {
                    if (IsNull(operation.LeftOperand) || IsNull(operation.RightOperand))
                        return;

                    // EntityFramework Core doesn't support StringComparison and evaluates everything client side...
                    // https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1222
                    if (operation.IsInExpressionArgument())
                        return;

                    context.ReportDiagnostic(s_rule, operation, $"{operation.OperatorKind} operator");
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool IsNull(IOperation operation)
        {
            return operation.ConstantValue.HasValue && operation.ConstantValue.Value == null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're just looking to have this analyzer to run on your own code and less interested in actually *writing* it, this is already implemented in the Microsoft-written analyzers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1307

Instructions for installation are available here:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers#microsoftcodeanalysisfxcopanalyzers

Our code for it is also available, but @meziantou's answer is a good example if you do want the simple code to start to understand analyzers.